# Are float pseudo-random number generators always implemented using integer generators underneath

Tags: floating-point, performance, pseudo-random-generators, c, random-number-generator

In C it's well known to use simple routine for turning integer rng into float rng. Something like that

```
float frand( float min, float max ) {
    float scale = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX; // [0, 1.0]
    return min + scale * (max - min); // [min, max]
}
```

So the core random number generation is happening inside integer rand() function which uses some sort of linear congruential generator. Is it always like that for floats?

Is there a better, more performant way if you specifically interested in float pseudo-random number generation in a given range (range is known on compile time)? This relying on integer arithmetic and float conversions seem wasteful to me, but on the other hand I have no idea how to implement it without it.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any direct-to-float PRNGs.  The primary issue is that it is very difficult to get high quality random numbers using floating point operations.  PRNGs typically leverage well understood integer behaviors to generate random-esque sequences with good properties.

Practically speaking, the subtractions and divisions are not all that wasteful.  Any PRNG you build using floats will be substantially more expensive.

The one case I can think of where you'd really want to use floats is if you had an extremely skewed distribution which is often very close to 0.  In this case, the extra precision of the float for small numbers would help.  Otherwise, the exponent part of the float doesn't really help you.  All you end up with is an integer PRNG in the mantissa part of the float, but with fewer bits than the higher quality and faster integer PRNGs would generate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When IBM created its POWER processors which may have been the first ones with a fused multiply-add operation, they managed to implement the linear-congruential method using floating point, generating large numbers of random numbers in parallel at a rate of one per cycle.

Comment: I guess they basically used their floating point units for integer-like manipulations on floats? I.e. they still used prime integer multiplier and modulo for linear-congruential formula?

Comment: IEEE 754 handles signed 54 bit integers (less than +/- 2^53). Fused multiply-add can handle 107 bit products if you are very clever. Yes, the result was identical to the linear-congruential formula.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have pointed out, most PRNGs using floating-point computation and floating-point storage for the PRNG state simply use the floating-point unit to perform integer arithmetic, using the significand part of IEEE-754 floating-point types to store the integers. One (historical) motivation for this is that hardware may support wider floating-point types than integer types.

One PRNG of this kind that has good quality and is still in wide-spread use today is MRG32k3a, which uses a sextuple of `double` variables for state. It first appeared in the literature in the late 1990s:

P. L'Ecuyer, "Good parameters and implementations for combined multiple recursive random number generators." *Operations Research*, Vol. 47, No. 1, Jan.-Feb. 1999, pp. 159-164

```c
#define norm 2.328306549295728e-10
#define m1   4294967087.0
#define m2   4294944443.0
#define a12     1403580.0
#define a13n     810728.0
#define a21      527612.0
#define a23n    1370589.0

double  s10, s11, s12, s20, s21, s22;

double MRG32k3a ()
   {
   long k;
   double p1, p2;

   /* Component 1 */
   p1 = a12 * s11 - a13n * s10;
   k = p1 / m1;   p1 -= k * m1;   if (p1 < 0.0) p1 += m1;
   s10 = s11;   s11 = s12;   s12 = p1;
   /* Component 2 */
   p2 = a21 * s22 - a23n * s20;
   k = p2 / m2;   p2 -= k * m2;   if (p2 < 0.0) p2 += m2;
   s20 = s21;   s21 = s22;   s22 = p2;
   /* Combination */
   if (p1 <= p2) return ((p1 - p2 + m1) * norm);
   else return ((p1 - p2) * norm);
   }
```

The use of `long k` was motivated by the absence of a way to round a floating-point-number to an integer using round-towards-0, i.e. truncation. However, since ISO-C99 there is the `trunc()` function which can be used for this purpose and maps to a single instruction on many modern processor architectures. This results in a pure floating-point computation, and modern compilers like Clang are able to use 2-way SIMD vectorization to parallelize the computation of `p1` and `p2`.

```c
double MRG32k3a (void)
{
    double k, p1, p2;

    /* Component 1 */
    p1 = a12 * s11 - a13n * s10;
    k = trunc (p1 / m1);  p1 -= k * m1;  if (p1 < 0.0) p1 += m1;
    s10 = s11;   s11 = s12;   s12 = p1;
    /* Component 2 */
    p2 = a21 * s22 - a23n * s20;
    k = trunc (p2 / m2);  p2 -= k * m2;  if (p2 < 0.0) p2 += m2;
    s20 = s21;   s21 = s22;   s22 = p2;
    /* Combination */
    if (p1 <= p2) return ((p1 - p2 + m1) * norm);
    else return ((p1 - p2) * norm);
}
```

Floating-point division is often fast on the latest (post 2020) processor implementations. Given that the divisors here are constant, it may nonetheless be worthwhile to try and [replace the division by constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527683/efficient-floating-point-division-with-constant-integer-divisors) with FMA-based computation utilizing a pre-computed reciprocal. FMA is a fused multiply-add operation that computes $a b +c$ that uses the *full* product $ab$ during the addition and applies a single rounding at the end. It was first introduced by IBM in the early 1990s:

Erdem Hokenek, Robert K. Montoye, and Peter W. Cook. "Second-generation RISC floating point with multiply-add fused." *IEEE Journal of Solid-State Circuits,* Vol. 25, No. 5, October 1990, pp. 1207-1213

At this point in time the major processor architectures all support FMA in hardware, and it is conveniently accessible via a standard function `fma()` in C, C++, and various other programming languages. Using FMA, we can create a bit-accurate replacement for  division by constant for many integer constants:

```c
/* compute quotient q=x/y for finite x, y; rcp_y = correctly rounded 1.0/y */
double qdiv (double x, double y, double rcp_y)
{
    double q;
    q = x * rcp_y;
    if (x != 0) q = fma (fma (-y, q, x), rcp_y, q);
    return q;
}
```

This results in the following implementation, which can likewise be SIMD vectorized by compilers like Clang:

```c
#define rcp_m1   (1.0/m1)
#define rcp_m2   (1.0/m2)

double MRG32k3a (void)
{
    double k, p1, p2;

    /* Component 1 */
    p1 = a12 * s11 - a13n * s10;
    k = trunc (qdiv (p1, m1, rcp_m1));  p1 -= k * m1;  if (p1 < 0.0) p1 += m1;
    s10 = s11;   s11 = s12;   s12 = p1;
    /* Component 2 */
    p2 = a21 * s22 - a23n * s20;
    k = trunc (qdiv (p2, m2, rcp_m2));  p2 -= k * m2;  if (p2 < 0.0) p2 += m2;
    s20 = s21;   s21 = s22;   s22 = p2;
    /* Combination */
    if (p1 <= p2) return ((p1 - p2 + m1) * norm);
    else return ((p1 - p2) * norm);
}
```

It should be noted that MRG32k3a can be efficiently implemented via pure integer computation on modern 64-bit processors. Even on 32-bit processors that provide an integer multiplier that can deliver the most significant 32 bits of the full product of two 32-bit integers an integer-based implementation can be reasonably efficient.

---

Part of programmer folklore in the world of 3D graphics is the following PRNG that uses only `float` computation and a two-vector of `float` variables for state storage.

```c
float rand(vec2 n) {
    return fract(sin(dot(n.xy ,vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 43758.5453);
}
```

This generates random numbers in $(-1,1)$ via `fract()`, which extracts the fractional part of a `float`. With the simple application of the absolute value, this could be used to generate random numbers in $[0, 1)$. For performance, this PRNG relies heavily on the availability of a blazingly fast `sin()` approximation, which is a standard feature of GPUs.

I have not used this PRNG and know nothing about its origin, design criteria, and properties. The small state and the non-linearity of the sine function *suggests* that it has a short period and provides a distribution that is not entirely uniform. Also, granularity of the generated numbers is limited as the significand of a `float` mapped to IEEE-754 `binary32` format comprises only 23 stored bits. There is a Q&A for this PRNG on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964279/whats-the-origin-of-this-glsl-rand-one-liner) which may be useful for followup.

Answer (score 1):

My very very first computer that came with BASIC built-in, had a random number generator that replaced the previous value x with the fractional part of (x + pi)^5.

It wasn’t very random. It had the interesting property that of two consecutive random numbers the second was larger with a probability of about 60% (or it was smaller. Can’t remember). The